# Fragment not displaying in fullscreen when using viewpager

Tags: android, android-studio, android-viewpager

I want my viewpager display fragment in the full screen.It is not displaying only in the half of the screen.I am stuck with this issue from past two days.So please help me to come out of this issue.Thanks in advance.

This is my activity code named activity_subcategory.xml -

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/main_layout"
android:orientation="vertical"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_arrow_back"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>
<!-- our tablayout to display tabs  -->
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    app:tabMode="scrollable"
    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/buttoncolor"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/buttoncolor"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>
<!-- View pager to swipe views -->
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This is my Fragment code named singlesubcategory.xml -

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgcat"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/laundry1" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/txtcat"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:weightSum="10"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="7"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:text="₹ 30"
            android:gravity="center"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_addtocart"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:text="0"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_removecart"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

[See this image. i want that card display in full width of screen.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7N9z.png)

This is my recyclerview code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/rcv"></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: make viewpager android:layout_height ro match_parent

Comment: change height of `ViewPager` to `match_parent` also make height of parent layout of `singlesubcategory.xml` `match_parent`

Comment: wrap_content replace with match_parent <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

Comment: looks like your recyclerview row item might be having width to `wrap_content`.

Answer (score 0):

> Change viewpager height

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
android:id="@+id/pager"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/rcv"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:foregroundGravity="center">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>


</LinearLayout>

Answer (score 0):

```
in your xml activity_subcategory.xml 

change parent Linear layout 
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/main_layout"
android:orientation="vertical"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
```

change height to fill parent.

Answer (score 0):

> Use this code

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:gravity="center"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/rcv"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:foregroundGravity="center">

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for view pager use fill parent

 <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    />
```

Comment: no this is not worked. But i got my issue. The problem was in this line LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.menu_rental_list_item, null); .....we have to use LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.menu_rental_list_item, parent, false);